# .attr('href') returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, window.location

I am using a simple JQuery solution to get the href from a link and apply it to a click event. This works in Webkit and Gecko browsers, however Internet Explorer (7 & 8) keeps displaying the href location as **undefined**. Anyone got a fix for this? Can help me solve this? Much appreciated if so.

```
 $('table tr').click(
    function () {
        var element = $(this).attr("class");
        var hrefLocation = $('#'+ element +' .deal-holder a').attr('href');
        alert(hrefLocation)
        window.location.href = hrefLocation;
        return false; 
    }
);
```

HTML is simple:

```
 <tr class="QRG">
    <td class="blue"><a href="#QRG">QRG</a></td>
    <td>Company Sale</td>
    <td>Technology</td>
 </tr>


 <div class="deal" id="QRG">
      <p><span class="js">Overview</span><span class="no-js">Enham</span></p>
      <div class="deal-holder">
         <div class="image-holder">
             <img src="../assets/images/enham.gif" alt="" height="70" width="150" />
         </div>
         <p>Enham is a charity established in 1918, which delivers a wide range of essential services that provide choice and empowerment to disabled people to make their own decisions about their lives. Enham is a charity established in 1918, which delivers a wide range of essential services that provide choice and empowerment to disabled people to make their own decisions about their lives</p>
         <a class="moreInfo" href="individual.html">More Information</a>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: That's your entire HTML document? [Please Make A Testcase](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Hi @jhui could you post an example of the html in your table tr please? ta.

Comment: Unless the class of the table row is the id of another elemnt, you aren't actually selecting anything. Could you post the html for the table containing the <a>?

Comment: Are you doing this *after* the DOM is loaded?

Comment: @Jim: I suspect that the class is the element name, especially since he said it works in non-IE browsers

Answer (score 4):

Nothing jumps out at me at being wrong.

First make sure your using the latest version of jQuery as that can sometimes help.

I change your code so the link within the `tr` has the click event:

```
$('table tr a').click(function (e) {
    var element = $(this).closest('tr').attr("class"),
        hrefLocation = $('#'+ element +' .deal-holder a').attr('href');
    alert(hrefLocation)
    window.location.href = hrefLocation;
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I did a demo <strike>[here](http://jsfiddle.net/DT4Pf/)</strike> and it works in IE 7,8 and 9. Hope this helps.

Comment: Problem is it isn't getting the href from a link in the table row. It is getting the href from a div with the same id as the tr's class.

Comment: var hrefLocation = $('#'+ element +' .deal-holder a').attr('href');

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the rest of your html code is difficult to know exactly what's your problem, the behaviour depends greatly on how your html is structured... But doing a quick test here it works: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Tgfhg/2/), just uses the `$(this)` pointer to get the child link.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to select the first element in the group of hyperlinks.

```
$('table tr').click(
    function () {
        var element = $(this).attr("class");
        var hrefLocation = $('#'+ element +' .deal-holder a').eq(0).attr('href');
        alert(hrefLocation)
        window.location.href = hrefLocation;
        return false; 
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in the ready function.
IE could be trying to add the event to the object, before it's in the DOM:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('table tr').click(
      function () {
         var element = $(this).attr("class");
         var hrefLocation = $('#'+ element +' .deal-holder a').attr('href');
         alert(hrefLocation);

         window.location.href = hrefLocation;
         return false; 
      });

});
```